# Para que sirve el fichero de strings.xml (resources) en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Hola estuve ejecutando mi app en android studio y me dieron varios errores en ese fichero, sobretodo en los nombres de las variables y me gustaria que alguien resolviese mi duda, gracias.

Comment: Y cuales son tus errores? No somos adivinos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Respuesta corta

Sirve para almacenar cadenas que pueden usarse en diferentes partes de la aplicación, sea en Java o en otras partes, como en archivos XML.

De ese modo, el valor de la cadena se encuentra definido en un solo sitio, y se hace referencia a ella mediante su atributo `name`.

La ventaja es que el código de la app es más flexible. Imagina una cadena que se repite cientos de veces en la app y luego tienes que cambiarla en cada lugar. Además, el tener las cadenas en un archivo de recursos facilita la traducción de la app a otros idiomas. Dicha traducción sería una tarea casi imposible si te dedicas a escribir a mano las cadenas por todas parte en la app.

Si tienes los valores de cadena solamente en los recursos de String la modificas allí y la cadena se actualiza automáticamente donde quiera que se use.

Al recurso string se hace referencia de la siguiente manera:

En Java: `R.string.string_name`

En XML: `@string/string_name`

#### Respuesta larga

Tener recursos como cadenas y otros (dimensiones, estilos, ...) forma parte de un conjunto de estrategias en el marco de la programación Android.

En Android Studio por ejemplo, cuando tienes una cadena escrita a mano en cualquier parte, te indica una advertencia de que debes convertir ese recurso... incluso AS busca si dicho recurso existe en el archivo de recursos y con un sólo clic te da la posibilidad de actualizarlo.

Por ejemplo aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje que aparece en el cuadro amarillo da dos motivos más que contundentes para aplicar el uso de recursos de cadena:

> Los atributos de texto de codificación directa en los archivos de
>   diseño son incorrectos por varias razones:
>
> - Al crear variaciones de configuración (por ejemplo, para paisaje o retrato), debe repetir el texto real (y mantenerlo actualizado al
>     realizar cambios)
> - La aplicación no se puede traducir a otros idiomas simplemente agregando nuevas traducciones para recursos de cadenas existentes.
>
> [En Android Studio y Eclipse] hay soluciones rápidas para extraer
>   automáticamente esta cadena codificada en una búsqueda de recursos.

Es por eso que AS recomienda cambiar la cadena *hardcoded*, por un recurso string, el cual además existe ya en este caso. La imagen muestra el cambio hecho del valor `Liturgia+` a la referencia del recurso `app_name`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo de recursos de cadenas (`strings.xml`), el recurso se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ese modo, si hace falta actualizarlo, lo haría solamente en `strings.xml`. En consecuencia, en cualquier layout que yo use: `android:text="@string/app_name"` o en cualquier código Java que use: `R.string.app_name` se mostrará el valor actual.

Puedes encontrar más detalles sobre el sentido de esta práctica en el apartado [Información general de recursos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html?hl=es-419), de Android:

> Siempre debes **externalizar los recursos** como imágenes y strings
>   del código de tu aplicación para que puedas **mantenerlos de forma
>   independiente**. Externalizar los recursos también te permite
>   proporcionar recursos alternativos que admiten configuraciones
>   específicas de los dispositivos, como idiomas o tamaños de pantalla
>   distintos, lo que cada vez es más importante, ya que más dispositivos
>   con tecnología Android están disponibles con configuraciones
>   diferentes. A fin de brindar compatibilidad con configuraciones
>   diferentes, debes organizar los recursos del directorio `res/` del
>   proyecto, para lo cual debes usar varios subdirectorios que agrupen
>   recursos por tipo y configuración.

Hay diferentes tipos de recursos String, los cuales vienen explicados en la página [Recursos de strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html?hl=es-419) de la documentación de Android.

Answer (score 0):

No son errores, son *"warnning"* es decir una advertencia.

El archivo `strings.xml` se utiliza para **almacenar todas las constantes de cadenas de caracteres** que se necesitan en un programa (por ejemplo las etiquetas de los objetos `Button`, los textos fijos de los controles `TextView` y todos los controles que muestran un texto fijo en el dispositivo)

> La idea fundamental es tener todos los mensajes que muestra nuestra
>   aplicación en un archivo (strings.xml)

Por ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como muestra la imagen el primer `String` es para el nombre de tu proyecto. y es llamado por el nombre `app_name`. Puedes crear diversos `String` como simple o Arrays entre otros.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Ash es muy buena y yo la daría por correcta, a ello añadirle la forma en la que se hace:

te creas una etiqueta string tal que asi:

```
 <string></string>
```

Ahora le das un nombre de forma que queda así:

```
<string name="colorFavorito"></string>
```

Finalmente pones el valor del recurso de modo que queda así:

```
<string name="colorFavorito">Rojo</string>
```

Ahora supongamos que tu layout luce así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Para conseguir lo que queremos finalmente le añadimos el atributo 'text' al textview con la referencia al recurso tal que queda así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/colorFavorito"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Es decir @string porque así se llama la etiqueta y luego el nombre que le has dado: (en nuestro caso 'colorFavorito') para que lo que finalmente se muestre sea lo que viene entre la etiqueta (en nuestro caso 'rojo')